# Does watir match this web application

Tags: security, internet-explorer, watir

We have this web application which works only in IE6.

The developers of the product have disabled the right click to prevent users from viewing the html source code, but I was able to workaround it using IE developer toolbar,but only partially successful.

Once you login,The whole application works in an IE page that opens as a pop-up.
Here I am able to view the source code in the developer toolbar.
But the application sometimes opens further popups,where I was unable to view the source code in the IE developer toolbar.

Having tasted success implementing watir in another test automation project and because i liked it very much coding in ruby,I was trying to do it again in watir.

The application is kind of complex one,with frames being used everywhere in the application.Here are few issues I have been facing.

1.Unable to identify the elements,frames,objects as the developers does not allow to view source code.
2.While I was able to access the elements using watir scripts in few pages,IE throws security error in few other ones.However the domain names of the pages in all the frames is the same.Is the anyway I can fix this security error once and for all?
3.Is there any other way to view the source code of the pages?
4.The application works only in IE6 and does not open in firefox.

Comment: need more details on what the security error is before we could suggest how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing that you have listed sounds like it would prevent WATIR from working as long as you have access to a machine with IE6 installed.

- Frames can be complicated for the script-writer, but WATIR supports
  them

  - http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Frames
- Many types of pop-ups are supported, too.

  - http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Pop+Ups
  - http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/JavaScript+Pop+Ups
- Disabled right-click menu does not apply as the @browser.html
  command can spit out the entire DOM.  Using IRB while coding will be
  highly beneficial
- The security errors and similar are either bugs
  that you should log before you begin to automate, or environment
  incompatibilities (you have a valid cert for PROD, but not for STAGE,
  etc) that you need to bring to the attention of your
  employer/developers. They either lose support for that feature, or bring it into a testable configuration.

Obviously since I do not know what company you work for, these are very high level observations and some assumptions have to be made.

Answer (score 0):

You gotta love an application that only works in a nearly 10 year old browser that nearly everyone including MS themselves [is trying to make DIE](http://www.ie6countdown.com/)  Not exactly what I would call a sustainable business model. unless your primary market is China. In most of the western world IE6 usage is under2% and in many under 1%..  But hey, you gotta work with what you got

In addition to the great tips that Adam offered, one of my favorite *'oh yeah, so you think you can hide from me'* tools is [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) Web Debugging Proxy.  If a site tries to obscure what it's doing, I fire up that puppy, do my best Al Pacino impression and tell the website: *"You wanna play Rough? Say hello to my little friend"* (yes, I talk to programs)

Fiddler2 is an HTTP level proxy and can even do 'man in the middle' to intercept HTTPS traffic. You can see each and every single file that goes into making up a web page.  Kinda bare metal in a way but it will lay everything a website is doing bare. There's no hiding from it. It also does a great job of providing formatting for lots of data types.  One of my favorite tools and I'm finding it invaluable in REST API testing that is my life at the moment.